# Text ending up on same line

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron

Im having troubles with my program today. Im writing a simple program in electron.js to send out payment talons to members from a excelfile.

The problem is when i try to print out the members name from a loop.

If i enter

```
'<p> ' + 'my name' + ' </p>' +
```

it works just fine but when i put a variable instead it gets all messed up.

```
 '<p> ' + first_name_val + ' </p>' +
```

[image]

entire javascript code:

```
var xlsx = require('xlsx');
var workbook = xlsx.readFile('./app/medlemmar.xlsx');

var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];
var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];
var members = [];
var count = 0;
var payed_count = 0;

for(var i = 12; i < 500; i++)
{
    var id = 'A' + i;
    var first_name = 'B' + i;
    var last_name = 'C' + i;
    var kommentar = 'H' + i;
    var betalt = 'J' + i;

    var d_id = worksheet[id];
    var d_first_name = worksheet[first_name];
    var d_last_name = worksheet[last_name];
    var d_kommentar = worksheet[kommentar];
    var d_betalt = worksheet[betalt];

    if(betalt_val == ' '){
        $("#pageswithpgtalon").append(
           '<div class="page">' +
          '<div class="from">' +
            '<h2>title</h2>' +
            '<p>Intresseförningen</p>' +
          '</div>' +
          '<div class="to">' +
              '<p> ' + first_name_val + ' </p>' +
              '<p>address</p>' +
          '</div>' +
          '<div class="textbox">' +
          '</div>' +
          '<div class="toplusgiro">' + 
            '49 87 85 - 5' +
         ' </div>' + 
          '<div class="paymentrecipient">' +
            'Joakim Wennergren' + 
          '</div>' +
       ' </div>'
        )
    } 

    var id_val = (d_id ? d_id.v : ' ');
    var first_name_val = (d_first_name ? d_first_name.v : ' ');
    var last_name_val = (d_last_name ? d_last_name.v : ' ');
    var kommentar_val = (d_kommentar ? d_kommentar.v : ' ')
    var betalt_val = (d_betalt ? d_betalt.v : ' ')

    if(betalt_val != ' '){
        payed_count++;
    }

    count++;

    if(!d_first_name)
        break;
}

$("#nusers").html(count);
$("#npages_with_pg").html(payed_count);
$("#npages_without_pg").html(count - payed_count);
```

and my css:

```
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
  font-size: 14px;
}

@media print {
   body {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
  }
}

@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";

@page {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
}

.freeh3{
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.freetext{
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px #eee;
  background: #fff;
}

*{
  color: #000 !important;
}

th{
  text-align: center;
}
td{
  text-align: center;
}

.jumbotron{
  background: #f8f8f8;
  margin: 0;
}
.jumbotron .btn{
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff !important;
}

.tablewrap{
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.table{
margin-top: 0;
}


body {

}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #cb3837;
}

.from{
position: fixed;
left: 20mm;
top: 180px;
font-size: 22px;
}

.to {
  position: fixed;
  right: 30mm;
  top: 160px;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.textbox{
  width: 75%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 340px;
  left:140px;
  max-height: 540px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.toplusgiro {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 400px;
  right: 200px;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.paymentrecipient{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 330px;
  right: 200px;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: left;
}


@media print {
  .page {
    page-break-after: always;
  }
}





.format{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
}

.page{
  /*height: 100%;*/
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;

  /*
background: repeating-linear-gradient(
  45deg,
  #000,
  #000 10px,
  #fff 10px,
  #fff 20px
);

*/

}
.col-md-6{
  padding: 40px;
  margin: 0;
}

.infobox{
  background: #fff;
  border: solid 1px #eee;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.btn-block{
  color: #fff !important;
}
```

Comment: you have a lot of fixed position, am pretty the issue is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made the position of the .from and .to classes fixed. That means that they will always be in the same position on your screen. It appears to work when you don't use a variable because then all .from-s and .to-s contain the same text, so you don't notice the overlapping.

Comment: Ok i didn't realized that while coding very late. Thanks for your answer! I changed .page to relative positioning and elements inside page to be absolute now and i works.